# Element is not clickable at point (56, 583). Other element would receive the click (behat)

Tags: behat

I am trying to click a button, but getting error Element is not clickable at point (56, 583). Other element would receive the click. I am using behat version 3.1.0-rc2

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GkCP.png)

Answer (score 1):

That error is quite self-explaining: when the driver tries to click an element, another in front of it, would receive the click.
Maybe your ajax isn't terminated yet?

I recommend you to take a look at [this](https://speakerdeck.com/doncallisto/behat-from-zero-to-hero-a-practical-guide-to-symfony-integration-and-usage) to improve either your test and stories